# Is there a reliable online backup service?

Tags: backup

We currently have multiple remote servers backing up about 50GB of total data to Mozy Pro.  unfortunately, we have had issues with Mozy not connecting or having a daily email alert generated.  Are there any truly reliable online backup services out there?  What might be great for personal use might not cut it here.

Edit: Reliable meaning that the automated backup will run without fail on a nightly basis, and the automated reporting will function without fail.  These are 2 things our existing service is not quite accomplishing.

Comment: What are your qualifications for reliable?  Five 9s uptime?  Four? Three?  Its really a subjective issue on what you consider reliable.

Comment: Edited to clarify what is desired with "reliable"

Comment: Have you looked at what is causing the reliability issues? It may not be the backup provider; what if it's your connection to the Internet that is causing issues? What is your connection specs?

Comment: In regards to connection, these are servers with uptime SLAs, the connectivity is stable.  Also, there are multiple remote locations, so it is not as if there is one hosting facility that has thr trouble.

Comment: Any idea what is causing the unreliable backups? Or is it pretty much that their service is just...um...not up to par?

Comment: The backups just say "connection problem" when they don't complete and the email alerts are supposedly a beta feature.  We'd just like to move to something a bit more stable and business oriented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use rsync.net, works like a charm with Mac book and Ubuntu.

Comment: I've used rsync.net myself and never had any trouble. They have a good attitude towards open standards and you transfer your files over ssh/sftp. They seem to have competent engineers and good storage technology on their side. They also recommend encryption of your data before backing it up (especially if you choose their server in the US).

Comment: I really like the flexibility and lightweight nature of rsync.net.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 3):

I have not used this myself, but I have been meaning to try after hearing good things about it from other co-workers.

http://www4.crashplan.com/landing/index.html

Comment: +1 CrashPlan is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I'd give CrashPlan a try.

Recent article in TidBITS:

[CrashPlan Central Slashes Hosted Backup Pricing](http://db.tidbits.com/article/10473)

I've not used their online service but I use their CrashPlan PRO server product on our own servers and storage, and they've been stellar.

Comment: A gentle reminder to upvote positive and helpful comments and suggestions, and mark the best.

Answer (score 0):

Symantec has an online backup offering called [SPN](http://www.spn.com) (Symantec Protection Network).

They have a few differnt flavors available: an online backup product, and a version that integrates within BackupExec. This allows BackExec to connect to and use the SPN storage directly as a distination for backups that are fully managed from within BackExec.

Comment: We use SPN.  They really need to get their act together before I can recommend them.  I gather that they are once again making progress on their product, but for a long time it felt very unfinished and neglected.  We're currently awaiting SQL, Exchange, and 64-bit agents of any kind.  Reporting leaves a lot to be desired as well.  Some of the data on the dashboard is flat out wrong.  "Have I really backed up more than 39872958279384 MB?"  I don't think so...

We'll stick with it, but it's not a clear cut winner yet.

Answer (score 0):

What is your budget? I did extensive research on this a few months back, and prices vary widely. A 50Gb (usually .50/GB) package on Mozy is not going to be nearly the same as someone like Iron Mountain ($9/GB)

There are other considerations, such as the type of data being backed up. Also, do you want 'protected' or 'stored'. Typically, 'protected' is uncompressed and no de-duplication, but less costly per GB.

To answer the question, i love Vaultlogix. http://www.dataprotection.com/

Comment: Meeting our needs at the lowest cost is the goal.  If our needs can not be met for less than $9/GB, then that will be our budget.  I'm in a fortunate position of shopping to get the job done, as opposed to see how much you can get with $X.

Answer (score 0):

I had a client having miserable luck with Mozy Pro. Backups were constantly failing / getting disconnected.

Then we changed their backup time from midnight to around 3 and 4 AM.  Never had an issue since...

---

That being said, I've had good luck with the LogMeIn Backup solution. Use their client, but you use your own storage. So if you have a couple sites or locations (or an office and a colo) with some extra storage at each you can easily and cheaply do offsite backups over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

We have had good luck with [digitliti](http://www.digitiliti.com/)  We get daily reports of what got backed up and they're rock solid reliable.  The even send warnings when there might be an interruption of service for their maintenance work.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard a lot of good things about Backup My Info, http://www.backupmyinfo.com/, while I do not work for them so this is not a marketing pitch they are very competitive and offer a great service.  I highly recommend checking it out.

If you decide to reach out mentionn Nick O'Neil from Logicworks for a discount.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Iron Mountain](http://www.ironmountain.com/dataprotection/server/) ... it is quite reliable.  You should have no availability issues and get the info that you need from them.

Be aware that they are more expensive than Mozy or Carbonite, but I imagine that the corporate data is more important than Joe Consumer's pictures.